# Laravel: Returning a view from a controller

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

I'm trying to learn how to use Laravel 5, but I've bumped into a problem. I've created the following code so far:
under `app/HTTP/routes.php`:

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'MyController@home');
```

Created my own `MyController.php` file under `app\Http\Controllers` and added the following code to the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;

class MyController extends BaseController
{
    public function home()
    {
        $name = "John Doe";
        return View::make("index")->with("name", $name);
    }
}
```

When I run the app I get the error:

```
FatalErrorException in MyController.php line 12:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\View' not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change

```
return View::make("index")->with("name", $name);
```

To

```
return \View::make("index")->with("name", $name);
```

or Even better

```
return view("index",compact('name'));
```

**UPDATE**

`View` is a [`Facade`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades), a wrapper class, and [`view()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-view) is a helper function that retrives a `view` instance.

Comment: Works fine. I'll accept your answer after 9 minutes (not allowed to accept it right now). Just another quick question, what's the difference between view and View::make

Comment: `View::make()` is from Laravel 4, this changed in 5 to the `view()` helper function as the use of facades is discouraged, although you can still use them for now. I'd expect they will become deprecated at some point if they're not already.

Comment: @n0t_a_nUmb3R- I have updated my answer with relevant links.